# Action extension not available when sharing a PDF from Safari

Tags: ios, xcode, info-plist

Our apps Action Extension needs to support all types of attachments. 
It works almost everywhere, the only case I can't get to work is when I try to share a PDF file opened in Safari. For example this one: 
https://carlosicaza.com/swiftbooks/SwiftLanguage.pdf

The app is not even appearing on the Share Sheet in Safari, I think there must be something missing in the `NSExtensionActivationRule` in the `info.plist` of the Action Extension target.

This is what the `NSExtensionActivationRule` looks like at the moment. I tried several things but no luck so far.

```
    <key>NSExtension</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsAttachmentsWithMaxCount</key>
                <integer>10</integer>
                <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsFileWithMaxCount</key>
                <integer>10</integer>
                <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsImageWithMaxCount</key>
                <integer>10</integer>
                <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsMovieWithMaxCount</key>
                <integer>10</integer>
                <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsText</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebURLWithMaxCount</key>
                <integer>1</integer>
            </dict>
        </dict>
        <key>NSExtensionMainStoryboard</key>
        <string>ShareSheet</string>
        <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.apple.share-services</string>
    </dict>
```

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: @Lucas Unfortunately not

Comment: I don't have a solution per se but I've noticed that Safari shares a PDF as two items: a URL and a PDF. On the top of the share sheet you can hit the blue options text and change the "Send as” to PDF. That will work as expected.